# Refreshing a listview make program very slow

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, listview

I'm new to C# and .NET programming and I'm trying to develop a windows TaskManager-like windows form application.
I first populate the listView by using infos gathered from System.Diagnostics.Process, then I start a System.Threading.Timer with a MethodInvoker delegate who try to refresh listview data every seconds.

The problem is that the application is ***really*** slow, and, for sure, I'm doing something noobish.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.Threading.Timer t;
        private Process[] procVett;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.loadAppInfo(null);
            TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(this.refresh);
            this.t = new System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, null, 1000, 3000);
        }


        private void refresh(Object stateInfo)
        {
            procVett = Process.GetProcesses();

            this.BeginInvoke( (MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                ListView.ListViewItemCollection ic = this.appList.Items;
                ListView.ListViewItemCollection procIc = this.procList.Items;
                time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                int count = 0;
                procList.BeginUpdate();

                foreach (Process p in procVett)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        string cputime = p.TotalProcessorTime.TotalMinutes.ToString();

                        procIc[count].SubItems[1].Text = ("");
                        procIc[count].SubItems[2].Text = (cputime);
                        procIc[count].SubItems[3].Text =(p.WorkingSet64.ToString());
                        procIc[count].SubItems[4].Text = ("");

                    }
                    catch (System.Exception)
                    {

                    }

                    count++;
                }
                procList.EndUpdate();

            }, null);

        }
}
```

Comment: We had it once as a homework and we all had the same problem in the class. However, try to run the app outside of the visual studio (Project dir/bin/debug/), debugging makes it a LOT slowlier.

Comment: the code is absolutely fine. i'd write the same probably. something else is affecting the app. try @nXu suggestion.. these winforms doesnt worth time to spend really.

Comment: running the program in a non-debug environment make it  'a lot' faster, as you said...even though, is still a little bit fuzzy...but I'll have a look at some of the improvement proposed :)

Answer (score 2):

You're basically on the right track, but I would avoid calling the BeginInvoke method until after you've looped through the processes in your array to collect the TotalProcessorTime time values.

Basically, the rule of thumb is to spend as little time on the UI thread as you can -- do as much work using background processes as you can.

Also, make sure you don't have threads or dispatches piling up in the thread pool. From the MSDN documentation for the Timer class:

> If the SynchronizingObject property is a null
>   reference (Nothing in Visual Basic), the Elapsed event is raised on a
>   ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer
>   than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool
>   thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.

So, watch for re-entrancy, and either ignore re-entrant timer events, or kill the processing on an older thread (using some thread-safe signaling mechanism).

Answer (score 1):

Apart of what I said in comment:

I'd say create a separated collection of ListViewItems, parse process informations into that in a different thread ([BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) or simply anothery thread) and use that collection in your ListView after you finished updating it, that way the currently displayed list won't be frozen.

Comment: mmm...ok, i thought about this solution, but I really don't know how to use a ListViewItems collection to add it to a ListView (except with doing a "Clear()" and ´foreach(ListItem item in Collection<ListViewItem>) { myListView.Add(item);}` wich seems  little bit dirty to me :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using VirtualMode on the ListView, which only displays the items currently in view. If you have 1,000,000 items, and it's only drawing #1,000-1020, it'll request those, you tell it how to get them from your item list in memory, and it draws them.

It's much faster than adding ListViewItems yourself, which is incredibly slow.

Here's a starter tutorial for it: [Virtual Mode ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42229/Virtual-Mode-ListView)

Also, I just started using [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) this morning, and it's amazing.

Comment: actually, the list size is indeed quite small, let's say about 10/15 items, and all of them are displayed...I don't get the benefits of using VirutalMode (even though it could be interestring for large data)